# Measuring the water vapour of room

Tags: humidity

Is it possible to measure the water vapour of my room in kg/litre if I know the volume,temperature and humidity of my room? If it is possible then how can I measure it?

Comment: do you know the relative or the absolute humidity ? you will need probably the temperature

Comment: ok I have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the absolute humidity or if you know the relative humidity and the temperature, it is easy.  There are tons of calculators online, such as [this one](http://www.lenntech.com/calculators/humidity/relative-humidity.htm).  If you look around a bit more, you'll find plenty of formulas for calculating dewpoint, densities, and so on.